# Assembly process video

Tags: animation

I'm new to Blender and I'll really appreciate it if anyone can give me advice on a project I'm working on right now.
I doing an assembly process video for a DIY product (step by step).
The product itself is a complex product with hundreds of parts (greenhouse) so I would need to have the parts appear only at the stage where they are supposed to be assembled. Unfortunately, I didn't find such an option in Blender, maybe someone know or can give me a tip that can help me with this project.
See reference: 
https://youtu.be/rfA2q9Prstw
Thanks

Comment: You can keyframe every property by hovering over it and pressing the ***I*** key. You could make transparent materials, then fade in their opacity with keyframes. You could also keyframe their Rendering and Viewport visibility in the outliner with keyframes (the *eye* and the *camera* icons).

Comment: ...and don't forget the flexibility which might be offered by splitting the action into shots, and simply cross-fading in an edit to introduce new components. That might split the project up into more manageable parts, letting you defer decisions about timing. etc..

Comment: Can you refer me to good video tutorial?